# "Implicit conversion from enumeration type" for animateWithDuration

Tags: objective-c, uiview, enums, implicit-conversion, animatewithduration

When trying to make an animation in `UIView` it says 'implicit conversion from enumeration type'

My code is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    [pea setFrame:CGRectMake(82, 224, 35, 35)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Just wondering how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn` is not a valid value for the [`animateWithDuration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW109) method. You presumably intended `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn` (note the `Option` in the constant name).

See [`UIViewAnimationOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptions) for a list of values to be used in conjunction with `animateWithDuration`. That constant you've used is intended for use with a different method.

Thus:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    [pea setFrame:CGRectMake(82, 224, 35, 35)];
} completion:NULL];
```